# Forgot my wamp mysql password

Tags: mysql, wamp

I forgot my wamp mysql password, i tried following the steps given in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html, but i'm getting a warning:

```
[Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option
```

Please help.

Comment: Your quesiton is unclear. Which password did you lose? Root or a specific user's password that was created by you?

Comment: Try using the instructions in C.5.4.1.3 of your link

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you what you need to lookup.

Edit my.ini and add this parameter

```
# Avoid warning
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = TRUE
```

If by the tag WAMP you mean WampServer put it in the `[wampmysqld]` section

Otherwise it should probably go in the `[mysqld]` section